# How to calculate percentiles from frequency table

Tags: r, percentage

suppose I have the following data:

```
data<-data.frame(col1=c(1,3,5,6),occurrences=c(10,4,5,8))
```

Which represents something like:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

How can I calculate the percentile 25 and 50?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `quantile` from `stats` package;

```
quantile(dB, c(.25, .50))
```

For your example data-set:

```
dB 
 #  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

This would be the answer:

```
# > quantile(dB, c(.25, .50))
#   25% 50% 
#   1   3
```

To make `dB` use the code below:

```
dB <- rep(data$col1, data$occurrences)
```

Comment: and what if I have only data<-data.frame(col1=c(1,3,5,6),occurrences=c(10,4,5,8))

Answer (score -1):

If you just want Q1 and the median (i.e. 25% and 50%) then following should work.

```
summary(data)
```

Comment: `data` is the frequency table. And `Summary` (even if it wasn't frequency table) gives us bunch of things including those percentiles not only them.